# How can I get output mention in below

Tags: haskell

```
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine
readInts :: IO [Int]

main = do
    putStrLn "List number of A: "
    num1 <- readInts
    let a = [] ++ num1
    putStrLn "List number of B: "
    num2 <- readInts
    let b = [] ++ num2
```

Choose some element a of A and some element b of B such that a + b doesn't belong to A and doesn't belong to B

Comment: What is `let a = [] ++ num1` supposed to do?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem yourself? What should be the signature of the core function that solves the problem?

Comment: making a list like this 

for example

A=[1,2,4]
B=[1,2,5]

Comment: but `num1`, is already a list of `Int`s. `([] ++)` is basically a no-op.

Comment: that's why i've posted this problem because im a beginner in Haskell hihi...

Comment: can you make at least to make a fair attempt to solve the real problem, not just the input/output?

Comment: i have an example for the problem:

if A = [2,1,7] and B = [1,3,4], we can choose 1 from A and 4 from B, as number 5 = 1 + 4 doesn't belong to A and doesn't belong to B. However, we can't choose 2 from A and 1 from B, as 3 = 2 + 1 belongs to B.

Comment: can you write an algorithm, for example in pseudocode. What would be the output here?

Comment: that's also my problem if what would be the output.

our instructor give us the problem without teaching us.

Comment: Try looking up list comprehensions in Haskell. That's probably the easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Serious**

If your instructor isn't teaching, and that isn't just you being burned out and stressed, then talk to the instructor.  They probably aren't trying to waste your and their time.  If that doesn't work then talk to the professor.

As for getting homework help here, it is entirely doable but help is very unlikely to appear without some semblance of an attempt and a clear cut issue.  You usually need to come to the table with *how* the problem can be solved and have problems translating that how into the specifics of *Haskell* or whatever target language.

**Cheeky**

A cheeky response I'd use if I were in the classroom:

This is a finite domain so I'd just use DPLL.  DPLL is a general purpose algorithm for finite domains that allows us to just state the problem as a symbolic computation and constraints then request satisfying models.   We'll construct the problem first then use the SBV library to get the model.

> Choose some element a of A

So lets define the set A (called `as`) as a list of symbolics and then constrain an existential to being a member of this set!

```
     a <- exists "value1"
     constrain (a `sElem` as)
```

> and some element b of B

OK, same thing.  We make a list of symbolic values and constrain an existential to being a member.

```
     b <- exists "value2"
     constrain (b `sElem` bs)
```

> such that a + b

Let's define an alias for this:

```
let c = a + b
```

> doesn't belong to A

We can just reuse the test for membership, `sElem`, and symbolic negation `sNot`.

```
constrain $ sNot (c `sElem` as)
```

> and doesn't belong to B

Yep, same!

```
constrain $ sNot (c `sElem` bs)
```

**Putting it together**

Honestly the hardest part is actually *running* your problem more than stating it.  We need to read the inputs (as you showed), call the solver (`sat`), and get the answer (aka the "model) via `extractModel` which can finally be printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
    build-depends:
        base, sbv >= 8.4
-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.SBV

readInts :: IO [Int64]
readInts = fmap read . words <$> getLine

readInt :: IO Int64
readInt = read <$> getLine

main =
 do putStrLn "List number of A: "
    a <- readInts
    putStrLn "List number of B: "
    b  <- readInts
    result <- getValues a b
    let values :: Maybe (Int64,Int64)
        values = extractModel result
    print values

getValues :: [Int64] -> [Int64] -> IO SatResult
getValues (map literal -> as) (map literal -> bs) = sat $
    do a <- exists "value1"
       constrain (a `sElem` as)

       b <- exists "value2"
       constrain (b `sElem` bs)

       let c = a + b
       constrain $ sNot (c `sElem` as)
       constrain $ sNot (c `sElem` bs)
```

Because this uses SBV you'll have to have first installed `z3`.  I included a cabal header to auto build as a package.  For example:

```
brew install z3
...
chmod +x mycode.hs
./mycode.hs
...
List number of A:
1 3 4 5
List number of B:
1 2 3
Just (3,3)
```

Comment: but i don't know how to install z3?

Comment: @Rvincent16, I think you're supposed to draw inspiration from this answer rather than actually using it. Could be wrong though. It may also be intended primarily as humor.

Comment: A bit of each. I wanted to convey why the asker wasn't getting help and what to do about that.  Also Z3 is cool if much less useful in a classroom setting like I suspect they're facing.